# Understanding what $\phi(f)(b,c) = f(b)(c)$ means

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, notation, definition

> Consider $\phi: (A^B)^C \to A^{B \times C}$ given by $\phi(f)(b,c) = f(b)(c)$.

I'm trying to understand the definition of $\phi$ as given above. Suppose $k \in A^B$. Then $k: B \to A.$ Now let $f \in (A^B)^C $. Then $f: C \to \{k\}$ meaning $f(c) = k_i$ for some $i$ and so $f(c)$ is a function and not just a value. Thus the notation $f(c)(b)$ makes sense...but I still can't make sense of what's going on with the definition of $\phi.$ What's the reasoning behind this definition if it's an acceptable question? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's write out what everything is. Part of this you already did in the question itself.

- $A^B$ is the set of functions $B \to A$, so an element $g \in A^B$ is just a function $g: B \to A$ and for each $b \in B$ that means we have some $g(b) \in A$;
- $(A^B)^C$ is the set of functions $C \to A^B$, so an element $f \in (A^B)^C$ is just a function $f: C \to A^B$ and for each $c \in C$ that means we have some $f(c) \in A^B$, by the above that is again a function $f(c): B \to A$, so for each $b \in B$ we get an element $f(c)(b) \in A$;
- $A^{B \times C}$ is the set of functions $B \times C \to A$, so an element $h \in A^{B \times C}$ is just a function $h: B \times C \to A$ and for each pair $(b, c) \in B \times C$ that means we have some $h(b, c) \in A$.

The point is that there is a natural bijection between $(A^B)^C$ and $A^{B \times C}$, and this is the map $\phi$ from your post. So $\phi$ is a function $\phi: (A^B)^C \to A^{B \times C}$. Thus given an element $f \in (A^B)^C$ we must produce an element $\phi(f) \in A^{B \times C}$, so $\phi(f)$ must be a function $B \times C \to A$. This function is defined by sending a pair $(b, c) \in B \times C$ to the value $f(c)(b)$ (this is also where there is a typo in your question, you wrote "$f(b)(c)$"). So notationally:
$$
\phi(f)(b, c) = f(c)(b).
$$

This correspondence is known as [Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). In words we can describe what happens as follows. For a function $f: C \to A^B$ we can turn it into a function $h: B \times C \to A$ by first evaluating $f$ at $C$, and then using that result and evaluating it at $B$. The inverse of this correspondence then goes as follows. If we are given $h: B \times C \to A$, then given some $c \in C$ we can turn it into a function $B \to A$ by fixing that $c$. That is, we get $h(-, c): B \to A$, which sends $b$ to $h(b, c) \in A$.

Comment: What's the inverse of $\phi$  a bit more explicitly? Given $h \in A^{B \times C}$ we want $\gamma(h) \in (A^B)^C$ with $\gamma(h): C \to A^B$ meaning $\gamma(h)(c) = h(b)(c).$ Would this formula work as the inverse of $\phi$?

Comment: @user762492 Almost, it is really given in my last sentence. The thing is $h(b)(c)$ does not really make sense, because $h$ takes pairs $(b, c)$ as input. Furthermore, $\gamma(h)(c)$ does not depend on $b$. You are right that $\gamma(h): C \to A^B$, and thus given $c$ we must get $\gamma(h)(c): B \to A$. Then we can just set $\gamma(h)(c)(b) = h(b, c)$.

Comment: @ Mark Kamsma, thank you. Sorry to bother you again, but this will be my last question. I am trying to compose the given expressions to show the result is identity. Since $f(c)(b), h(b, c) \in A,$ do we get $f(c)(b)h(b, c) = (a)(a)$? Does that even make sense? Do we have to use another method to show the functions are inverses?

Comment: @user762492 The composition has to be the identity on $(A^B)^C$ one way around, and the other composition has to be the identity on $A^{B \times C}$. So no identity on $A$ is involved. I will do one for you: start with $f \in (A^B)^C$, then writing out what we discussed before gives $\gamma(\phi(f))(c)(b) = \phi(f)(b, c) = f(c)(b)$ for all $b$ and $c$, so $\gamma(\phi(f)) = f$. Thus we see that $\gamma \circ \phi$ is the identity. Now you try the other composition.

Comment: @ Mark Kamsma, Now $\phi(\gamma(h))(b, c) = \gamma(h)(c)(b) = h(b, c)$ and so $\phi(\gamma(h)) = h$ meaning $\phi$ and $\gamma$ are inverses. I see the logic of the situation now. Thank you very much.